# How to move a shape after drawing it

Tags: c#

I have a problem while moving the shape that i drew, when i click on the line and drag it, it becomes 2  lines,i think the problem is in my mouse event code, here is my mouse event code:

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (obj.IsPointOnLine(e.Location, 5) == true)
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
                obj.isDragging = true;
                deltaStart = new Point(obj.mstartpoint.X - e.Location.X, obj.mstartpoint.Y - e.Location.Y);
                deltaEnd = new Point(obj.mendpoint.X - e.Location.X, obj.mendpoint.Y - e.Location.Y);
            }
            else if (obj.IsPointOnLine(e.Location, 5) == false)
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
                obj.mstartpoint = e.Location;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (obj.isDragging && deltaStart != null && deltaEnd != null)
        {
            obj.mstartpoint = new Point(deltaStart.X + e.Location.X, deltaStart.Y + e.Location.Y);
            obj.mendpoint = new Point(deltaEnd.X + e.Location.X, deltaEnd.Y + e.Location.Y);
            Refresh();
            Update();
        }
        else if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) != 0)
        {
            if ((Control.MouseButtons & MouseButtons.Left) != 0)
            {
                obj.mendpoint = e.Location;
                switch (obj.mshape)
                {
                    case 1:
                        obj.mshape = 3;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        obj.mshape = 4;
                        break;
                }
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
        else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            obj.mendpoint = e.Location;
            switch (obj.mshape)
            {
                case 3:
                    obj.mshape = 1;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    obj.mshape = 2;
                    break;
            }
            Invalidate();
        }          
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        obj.isDragging = false;
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        MyObject a = new MyObject(obj.mstartpoint, obj.mendpoint, obj.mshape, obj.mwidth, obj.mcolor);
        ds.Add(a);
    }
```

If you dont get it download my source code:https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdk88k4661zc3nj/WindowsFormsApplication19.rar
Please fix my problem and thank you,sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

If want to implement a canvas to drag elements, a DragCanvas is your choice.

[Dragging Elements in a Canvas **from Josh Smith**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15354/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas) and after [Dragging Elements in a Canvas **from igkutikov**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/387977/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas) that adapt Josh Smith code. There are articles with #mustread category.

With the dragCanvas you can implement a full functionality Dragging Element Canvas, and better adapt to your code. Happy coding!